# UICollectionView Memory Leak

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi i am having a memory leak issue with the code bellow once my application is tested on the physical device. My problem occurs when scrolling a `UiCollectioView` dow but is also very slow on the load up of this view controller.

So what i am truing to do is use a `NSFileManger` to load images directly from the iPhones DCIM file located at this path /var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/. After fetching these images i place them into an array and create a sort of gallery with them through the `UICollectionView` by populating each cell with the list of images in the array. For example cell 1 = image 1, cell 2 = image 2 and so forth. This works correctly but when scrolling crashes unexpectedly but forcefully so i am therefore assuming this is a memory leak problem. Especially when this problem does not occur on the simulator.

Here is my code:

```
    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
        path = @"/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/";
        Images = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil]mutableCopy];
    }

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if ([[[Images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"JPG"])
    {
    [collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", path, [Images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]]];


    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, cell.bounds.size.width, 20)];
    v.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor]colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4f ];

    UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, cell.bounds.size.width, 40)];
    title.tag = 200;
    title.text = [Images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    title.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:v];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:title];
    return cell;
    }
    else
        [collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return Images.count;
}
```

Thanks in advance...

**PS:
My app is being built as an app for jailbroken phones so please do not tell me that apple will not accept the way i am doing this.**

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't assume you have a memory leak as it's pretty uncommon when using ARC; you should use instruments to test. You have a problem in that you're adding the view, v, and the label, title, to cells that already have them when you scroll, and cells are reused. This is most likely your problem. Personally, I think it's bad form to add subviews in cellForItemAtIndexPath, unless you're adding them to some cells and not others based on the indexPath. You should create a custom cell, and add the subviews in its init method (or in IB). Also, you only need to register the class once, so it shouldn't be in cellForItemAtIndexPath; a better place to put it would be viewDidLoad.

Comment: Ive removed the code that adds the subviews but the application is still crashing?

Comment: @user2874682, are you getting a crash log?